# T- SQL compare two date column and find month number

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, compare, case

I am new in this business. hope you could help me to sort out below problem with CASE Statement. I need to compare two columns where date values are there but the result will be as like as the picture below.

Thank you
Nayeem

[image: T SQL example with date]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
select
    first_date
    ,second_date
    ,case 
        when first_date > second_date
            then
                substring(datename(month,first_date),1,3) + '-' + substring(datename(year,first_date),3,2)
        else
            substring(datename(month,second_date),1,3) + '-' + substring(datename(year,second_date),3,2)
    end as result
from (
    select CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-25') as first_date ,CONVERT(datetime, '2017-02-02') as second_date
    union
    select CONVERT(datetime, '2018-01-25') as first_date ,CONVERT(datetime, '2018-12-04') as second_date
    union
    select CONVERT(datetime, '2019-11-14') as first_date ,CONVERT(datetime, '2019-11-14') as second_date
) x;
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date columns are indeed `date`s, you seem to be looking for:

```
select format(coalesce(start_date_1, start_date_2), 'MMM-yy')
from t;
```